# Django RSS feed

Tags: django, frameworks, feed, syndication

I am trying to develop a simple site that:

1- Automatically fetch from my db the 5 latest entries. Entries are news headline titles that I input manually.

2- display these entries on a simple webpage (no fancy formatting or anything else)

**3- The site periodically searched for newly posted entries and displays them without having the user refreshing the webpage.**

I am using Django, learning how to implement different functions as I go.

**Question** (to be able to implement point 3):

1- Is RSS feed what I should be looking for? Django has the syndication feed framework and I am wondering if I should use it or not.

2- If RSS is not the way to go, can someone point me to right path / possible tutorial that might help me out? I am stuck on this and new to web programming.

Thx in Advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to have content change "without having the user refreshing the webpage" is to use Javascript. So you'll need to write some JS that fires off an AJAX request to the Django server, pulls in the latest blog entries, and displays them on the page, then sets a timeout for the next execution in x minutes.

I'm not sure why you want this to be on a web page though. If you want an RSS reader, use one of the many that are out there already.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a normal blogging framework that you need. There are a lot of examples for such a setup.

http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Install_Django_and_Build_Your_First_App/

Comment: I don't think that the blog tutorial will help me achieve what I want. I know how to set an application work with forms ect... What I am interested in at this stage is having a functionality to automatically fetch  new entries without the user manually refreshing the page.